# What is Glymour's theory of bootstrap confirmation?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, bootstrapping, confirmation, clark-glymour

I take it that the idea is that we can go from *relative* confirmation (confirmation of a hypothesis relative to auxiliary assumptions), to absolute confirmation, by testing any hypotheses that a theory contains against each other; but how is this supposed to work (in simple terms)?

(The [SEP entry on confirmation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/confirmation/) apparently doesn't have anything to say about it.)

**What is [Glymour's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clark_Glymour) theory of bootstrap confirmation?**

Comment: He's trying to show the existence of real confirmation of some scientific hypothesis with variable set of auxiliary assumptions could be iteratively reached in a convergent manner not unlike bootstrap random sampling with replacement commonly used in stats as a type of resampling method, it may have the same effect as falsification in practical reality though when applied in philosophy of science...

Comment: Standard reference is [Douven-Meijs, Bootstrap Confirmation Made Quantitative](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20118726):"*Glymour presents a confirmation theory on which the piecemeal confirmation of the individual hypotheses comprised by a given theory relative to other hypotheses comprised by the same theory may add up to an unrelativized confirmation of that theory as a
whole. Whether it does, depends on whether the separate tests of the various hypotheses might have turned out negative for these hypotheses.*"

Comment: https://www.cmu.edu/dietrich/philosophy/docs/glymour/glymour1980b.pdf

Comment: https://iep.utm.edu/confirmation-and-induction/

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap Confirmation is a scientific method designed to help us connect our observations, measurements, and predictions in a systematic manner. This leads to a better understanding of the world around us, and it helps reduce incorrect assumptions.

Let's dive back into an example of wanting to find out if wearing red shoes helps you run faster.

Step 1: Data Collection
We gather data by watching kids' races, noting the shoe color of each participant and recording who wins. This gives us raw information to analyze later.

Step 2: Model Building
Next, we visualize the data collected by creating diagrams or charts that display the correlation between shoe color and winning. For example, we may plot the percentage of victories for athletes wearing red shoes against those with other colored shoes.

Step 3: Model Verification
Using the model, we can make predictions about our friend's chances of winning a race based on their shoe color. We watch their race and compare the predicted winner with the actual result.

Step 4: Iterative Improvement
Based on the comparison between our predictions and the actual results, we decide if our assumptions are correct or not. If needed, we modify the model, collect more data, fine-tune our assumptions, and repeat the cycle.

Comparing Bootstrap Confirmation to Hypothetico-Deduction (HD):

Imagine a detective looking for a criminal based on footprints left behind. Traditionally, detectives would create a story in their minds about who committed the crime and then seek clues that match the narrative. This leaves room for confirmation bias and may implicate innocent people.

With Bootstrap Confirmation, we eliminate unnecessary speculations and stick to collecting concrete data and evidence. This allows us to stay honest in our quest for answers.

By following this method, we can confidently address questions and arrive at well-supported conclusions.

Sources:

Glymour, Clark. (1980). Theory and Evidence. Princeton University Press.
Glymour, Clark. (2001). Does Philosophy Need Science? Daedalus, 130(2), 101-116.
Woodward, James. (2011). Making Things Happen: A Theory of Causal Explanation. Oxford University Press.
Sloman, Steven. (2005). Causal Models: How Users Think, Represent, and Learn About Mechanisms. Lawrence Erlbaum Associates.

Answer (score 0):

It is a mathematical theory so it is best to focus on comprehending the core mathematical aspects; a subjective interpretation follows more readily.

Working with the PDF page numbers of this PDF (cmu.edu/dietrich/philosophy/docs/glymour/glymour1980b.pdf):

Page 3:

```
Let L be a language.
Let Q be a set of quantity terms in L.
Let S be the set of well-formed claims of L involving Q.

Suppose there is a set Q* of quantitites, such that a quantity q* of type n maps members of a subset of any set of ordered n-tuples of individuals into the real numbers R.

Let Q* be closed under the usual algebraic operations.

A possible situation w* is a pair consisting of a set of individuals (or domain) and a set of quantities mapping members of the domain, or members of Cartesian powers of the domain, into the reals.

W* denotes the set of all possible situations.

For an ordered n-tuple I_n of individuals, q*(I_n, w*) will denote the value of q* for I_n in situation w*.

Dom(q*) will denote the set of all sitautions tow hich q* belongs.

w* \entails s means that sentence s holds in situation w*.

For subsets Z of Q*, a probability measure prob_z on the set Dom(Z) =_df \intersection {q* \in Z} {Dom(q*)}

For a sentence S and a set Z of quantities, define prob_z (s) =_df prob_z {w* \in Dom(Z) | w* \entails s}
```

This is already enough to study for now. I will return to later parts of the paper after trying to clarify the above.

---

One time the mathematician John Baez gave me the beginner's advice to "focus on the definitions" and I believe this is very good advice. I recommend treating mathematical definitions like you might study vocabulary if you were learning a new language, quizzing yourself with flashcards or something. You will need those definitions mastered to follow an argument. (In situations like these its too bad we don't have mathtype enabled on our site; I will personally look into how we could enable that.)

## Clarification

- As a "language", L appears to be a tuple - essentially, it "contains data". All we know so far is that one of the things it "contains" is Q. It may contain other things as well.
- Q is a set. Specifically, it is a set of "quantity terms", but we do not have a definition of what that is yet, so let's not worry about it.
- S is also a set. Specifically, it is a set of claims. More specifically, it is a set of claims "of L". Thus, it appears that another thing L "contains" is "a set of claims". More specifically, S is a specific subset of the set of claims L contains. Specifically, it is the subset of claims of L which "involve Q" (we do not yet have a clear definition of what it means for a claim to "involve" Q, so we should not yet worry about what this means. We would not be able to proceed until we get that definition.)
- Q* is a set of quantities.
- A quantity q* is actually a mapping, a.k.a a function. It can also be thought of as a "dependent type" (I think - I need to double check), in that it takes an argument, 'n', and produces something which depends on 'n'. Specifically, n appears to be a natural number. The definition we have so far is, "a quantity q* of type n maps members of a subset of any set of ordered n-tuples of individuals into the real numbers R." Let's break that down:

  - There is some "set of all n-tuples". These are tuples of "individuals" (whose definition we hope to receive later in the article). For this set of "all n-tuples", we can pick a subset of them. (This is essentially combinatorics. Let's assume there are M total individuals that exist, in some context. Let's choose some number n, as the number of individuals we want to consider, at any given time. The number of possible (ordered) n-tuples of M individuals is a classic mathematical function, that of "permutations". I am not sure the perfect combinatorics term but the important thing is we do not allow duplicate elements in the tuples, I believe, so it's very likely a factorial function but I need to double-check.) All we know so far is that this "quantity function" q* only maps a *subset* of those permutations, so it picks some of the selections of individuals. It doesn't have to map all of them.
  - And it maps them "into the real numbers". The important thing to emphasize is, it maps a single tuple of individuals "into the real numbers". My guess is this is some sort of "metric" - maybe it's a probability metric, like, a tuple of n hypothesis altogether is mapped to "probability of truth 0.75". (It remains to be seen.)
- So the above definition is kind of complicated, but not if you break it apart into simple steps. 1. Choose a set of "individuals" (say, Sarah, Clara, and Jenny). 2. Choose a number (n) which will be the size of the arrangements (say, 2). 3. In this case, there are 3P2 = 6 possible arrangements (Sarah then Clara, Sarah then Jenny, Clara then Sarah, Clara then Jenny, etc.), but we are free to choose a subset of those possible arrangements. For example, we just choose "Sarah and Jenny" and "Clara and Sarah". Finally, our "quantity function" maps each of those arrangements to some real number (we don't know why, right now): "Clara and Sarah" -> 103.777777... (etc.).

Thank God we can move on now.

- Q* is closed "under the usual algebraic operations". I personally think a mathematician would object to this, as they ought to specify what algebraic operations they have in mind. Maybe there is a convention in the author's field. Maybe it will become clearer later, but I personally think it is too hard to surmise what they mean. Q* is a set of functions. These functions are not closed under compoition, since the input/domain and output/codomain are not the same set. If we think of the q* function as a *metric*, maybe there is a defined set of rules/axioms which make it behave like a metric commonly does - q*(s1 + s2) = q*(s1) + q*(s2), for example. I need to think about the mathematics of this later, but this gives a hint. In abstract algebra, I think this counts as a "group action" or something similar.
- A possible situation is a pair (which is a 2-tuple). It contains a set of individuals, and a set of quantities. Recall that a "quantity" is actually a function mapping groupings of individuals to real numbers. (So far, the term "quantity" doesn't sound like an intuitive name for this, but rather "metric" or something, but we'll see as we go along. If the second member of this tuple is a "set of quantities", it sounds like it provides a number of *possible* metrics on that set of individuals. (For example, a group of people could be mapped to their collective weight, collective height, collective age, etc. If my understanding is correct so far.)
- W* denotes the set of all possible situations.
- I_n is one specific ordered tuple of individuals (one specific possible arranging of them).
- Therefore, q*(I_n, w*) is a function (the "quantity function") on that specific set of individuals, but it also takes into account w*.
- Remember, a situation is a pair: the general set of individuals, and a set of quantities. I am starting to worry the formalization here is horrible, as we basically have a nearly circularly definition of a quantity as a function taking a situation as an argument, but a situation being defined as a collection of individuals and quantities. Let's not worry too much about this and see where this is headed, then maybe we can present a simpler formalization.
- q* intuitively represents "a value for some set of individuals in some situation".
- Dom(q*) is "the set of all situations where q* belongs" (the domain of q*).
- w* entails s means sentence s, which comes from language L, holds in situation w* (by the way, the choice of w is probably influenced by the use of w as a "world" in possible worlds semantics).
- For a subset Z of Q*, the set of all quantities, a probability measure can be defined on the domain of that subset Z. The domain of that subset is the intersection of the domains of all the specific q* quantities in the the subset Z (this is trivial but might sound complicated, I can simplify the explanation.)
- The probability of a sentence s with regards to to a set of quantities Z is defined as the probability of all the situations which entail the sentence s.

This is already enough to study for now. I will return to later parts of the paper after trying to clarify the above.

You should aspire to memorize these definitions as you would foreign language vocabulary with flashcards. You will need to know it, in order to understand.

(more to come soon, hopefully. This is just an intro. I'll try to simplify my presentation when I myself understand it better.)

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could give you a better answer, but this question piqued my interest enough to make me appreciate how worthy of study the work of Clark Glymour’s is, so all I can give is a very simple and brief one.

This IEP article does give a convenient summary of the idea. I’ll try to pad it out with my own interpretation of it.

> Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy.
> “Evidence: iii. Bootstrapping”.
> https://iep.utm.edu/evidence/#SH2ciii

> The basic idea of Glymour’s bootstrapping theory (1975, 1980) is quite simple: to test an hypothesis in a theory consisting of several hypotheses, all of which contain theoretical terms, we can use those other hypotheses in the theory, together with observational evidence, to derive a positive instance of the hypothesis we are testing and obtain evidence for it.

To test a hypothesis within some theory, we can use the other hypotheses in that theory to try to mathematically confirm the first hypothesis. That is, because hypotheses are logically bound to each other, we can try to show how one of them is or is not more deeply related to the other ones.

> By repeating this process for each hypothesis in the theory, we can obtain evidence for (or against) the theory as a whole, even though the theory employs a theoretical vocabulary, while the evidence is couched in an observational one. In such a case, we are “pulling ourselves up by our own bootstraps”, in the sense that we are using certain bits of a theory to obtain evidence for other bits of the same theory, in the service of obtaining evidence for (or against) that theory as a whole.
>
> To fill-in this abstract characterization, consider one of Glymour’s historical examples. Newton’s law of universal gravitation asserts that all bodies exert an inverse square attractive force upon one another. As evidence for this, he used Kepler’s laws of planetary motion.

Here we have a general theory of gravitation, containing a hypothesis about a formula characterizing gravitational force, which refers to Kepler’s laws as evidence for that hypothesis.

> Yet none of Kepler’s laws contains the theoretical term “force”; they merely describe observable regularities in the planets’ orbits without offering any theoretical explanation for them.
>
> How, then, do we link the observable evidence - Kepler’s laws — to an hypothesis that contains the term “force”, so that the former can become evidentially relevant to the latter?
>
> The evidential link is supplied, of course, by other parts of Newton’s theory, namely his second law of motion relating the force on a body with the measurable quantities of mass and acceleration.

There was no deeply rigorous reason to consider Kepler’s observations about the irregular patterns in planetary motion to be ‘evidence’ of Newton’s proposed mathematical formula for gravitational force.

> Newton used the second law and the evidence of Kepler’s laws to derive instances of the law of universal gravitation for planets and their satellites.

However, Newton had a second hypothesis in his general theory of gravitational force, which related “force” to other quantities like mass and acceleration.

Newton was able to use Kepler’s observations of patterns in planetary motion as confirming evidence of his hypothesis relating the matter and acceleration of an object to its force (presumably, the force of the planets on each other influencing the patterns by which they moved).

After having supported a hypothesis about force, his second hypothesis (about how all matters exerts an attractive force, not just planets) was in some way related to, dependent on, built on, or buttressed by his first hypothesis.

> He eventually generalized this law to all bodies in the universe. Despite being the briefest sketch of Newton’s argument, this illustrates Glymour’s point: here Newton is using observational evidence and other hypotheses in a general theory under test to derive instances of — and thus evidence for — a particular hypothesis in that theory, even though the evidence and the hypothesis employ different vocabularies.

Thus - since you wanted a “simple explanation” - we can say Glymour’s theory is a mathematical model showing how through a chain of probabilistic functions, evidence from one domain can be related to a hypothesis from a different one. When this happens, the increased calculated “probability” of that hypothesis can be used in turn to increase the probability of some further hypothesis. Eventually, perhaps many of the hypotheses can be shown to have mutual connections or dependence. Thus, it is comparable to ideas in machine learning and statistical inference, where by finding an initial hypothesis that explains some data well, it helps one formulate a second hypothesis which explains the data even better, but the second one was not accessible until the first one was discovered.

The core presentation of the theory is at the bottom of page 692 in the journal issue of its publication:

> Evidence *E*, a collection of formal sentences in a logical language *L*, confirms hypothesis *h*, another sentence in language *L*, with respect to theory *T*, another collection of sentences in *L*, if there is a subtheory *T0* (a subcollection of the sentences in *T*), for which, for all quantitative terms in sentence/hypothesis *h*, and for all situations which would provide relevant evidence for *h* (that is, in which the quantitative terms of *h* take values), the probability of that hypothesis is greater in that context than either of the probability of that hypothesis alone (i.e. in general), or the probability of that hypothesis in the theory without making use of evidence *E*.

That is my attempt to parse that cumbersome mathematical definition on page 692 and I don’t know if it’s right. I hope it can give you a simpler idea to think further about which parts of it may need some revision. I think the intuitive idea is that if you can show that a hypothesis is more confirmed by a certain body of evidence than it would be without the evidence, we call that “confirmation”; and the idea is to do that repeatedly over a chain of hypotheses.